# python, instance of object in another file

Tags: python, object, import

This maybe a dumb question, but I'm gonna ask it anyways. I have a creature file and a simulation file, each contain a class of the same name. In the Simulation class's init, I need to initialize two Creature object. I have imported the creature file, but when I try creature.Creature() I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lego90511/Documents/workspace/creatureSim/simulation.py", line 2, in <module>
    import creature
  File "/Users/lego90511/Documents/workspace/creatureSim/creature.py", line 3, in <module>
    import simulation
  File "/Users/lego90511/Documents/workspace/creatureSim/simulation.py", line 86, in <module>
    sim = Simulation(5)        
  File "/Users/lego90511/Documents/workspace/creatureSim/simulation.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.creatures = {creature.Creature(4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 10):"", creature.Creature(4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 10):"", }
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Creature'"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the relevant code:

Simulation:

```
import creature
from random import randint
class Simulation():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.creatures = {creature.Creature():"", creature.Creature():"", }
        ...
```

Creature:

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(self, social, intelligence, sensory, speed, bravery, strength, size):
        self.traits = [social, intelligence, sensory, speed, bravery, strength]
        ...
```

Comment: I get no such error when running your code.

Comment: Running your code on my PC leads to no such error but you should give enough arguments to Creature.

Comment: I've added the full error text incase that reveals anything thing more. Could it have something to deal with using python 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. `creature` is importing `simulation`, which in turn is trying to import `creature`, so it fails. You'll need to structure your files a different way to remove the circularity - either put both classes in one file, or move one import inside a function.